# Simpson's rule in numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

In the following code I have implemented composite Simpson's rule. However I should be getting approximately $291$ but for some reason I am getting something different. I implemented a few other methods to test it and the proper answer was $291$ So how do I fix my code?

```
from math import pi,cos,sin
def SimpsonMethod(f,a,b,n):
    h = (b-a)/n
    s = f(a)+f(b)
    for i in range(1,n,2):
        s+=4*f(a+i*h)
    for i in range(2,n-1,2):
        s+=2*f(a+h*h)
    return s*h/3
 print(SimpsonMethod(lambda x: x**2,5,10,100))
```

giving the output

```
237.39917687499988
```

Comment: There are  related sites in this group of sites for coding Q's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in the part of the function that calculates the even nodes, should be `s+=2*f(a+i*h)`, this is after fixing:

```
from math import pi,cos,sin
def SimpsonMethod(f,a,b,n):
    h = (b-a)/n
    s = f(a)+f(b)
    for i in range(1,n,2):
        s+=4*f(a+i*h)
    for i in range(2,n-1,2):
        s+=2*f(a+i*h)
    return s*h/3.
print(SimpsonMethod(lambda x: x**2,5,10,100))
```

and the result

```
291.66666666666674
```

Comment: thanks for the submission! I see where I went wrng

Comment: @fr14 Happy to help

Comment: I have posted another question using gauss quadrature